# Regex Matching Behaviour Of \w

Tags: regex

I noticed some interesting behaviour with some regex work I am doing, and I'd like some insight.

From what I understand, the word character, \w should match the following [a-zA-Z_0-9]

Given this input,

> 0000000060399301+0000000042456971+0000000

What should this regex

> (\d+)\w

Capture?

I would expect it to capture 0000000060399301 but it actually captures 000000006039930

Is there something I am missing? Why is the 1 dropped from the end?

I noticed if I changed the regex to

> (\d+\w)

It captures correctly i.e. including the 1

Anyone care to explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d+` - matches one or more digit characters.

`\w+` - matches one or more word characters. `[A-Za-z\d_]`

So with this string `0000000060399301+`, `\d+` in this `(\d+)\w` regex matches all the digits (*including the 1 before +*) at very first, since the following pattern is `\w` , regex engine tries   to find a match, so it backtracks one character to the left and forces `\w` to match the digit before `+` . Now the captured group contains `000000006039930` and the last `1` is matched by `\w`

Answer (score 3):

You require the regex to match a trailing word character - that would be the `1`.

It cannot be another character, because

- `+` is not a word class character
- `+` is not a digit
- matching is greedy

Answer (score 1):

The 1 is being dropped because \w isn't in the capture group.